Re: Salesforce Apex: Dates
Re: Salesforce Apex: Dates
Keep getting this error message.
Compile error: Variable does not exist: hello
Line: 6
public with sharing class Solution {
  private String dateAsString = '2019-01-01 00:00:00';

  public Integer getDay(Date someDate) {
    Date hello = Date.newInstance(2024, 7, 11);
    return hello;
  }
}


Don't name your class Solution, that's a standard object's name. It's like public Integer Account = 5; // happy debugging suckers
You're sure the file saved (on your disk) OK before you attempted deployment? I'm getting Illegal conversion from Date to Integer (6:7)
But if I change that line to return hello.day(); it compiles OK.
